# Better Magento2 data management

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute, attribute-set

At our company, we have a lot of products, almost all have color attribute assigned to them.
As a result of that we have a lot of color options (hundreds).

I was wondering if we can maybe manage this a little better. Should we split this color attribute and use a different one for each product type? As an example of what I mean: `running_shoe_color`, `gym_bag_color`, `tshirt_color`, etc...

Or should we keep it they way it is currently?

Looking for answers from people who already had experience with managing such amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand for what reason your are going to use color attributes. If you want to show this attributes on detailed page - better to have different color attributes and it's allows to manage colors per product kind.

If you are going to show color attributes as filter on category page is also useful for customer to have different kind of color options.

As I correct understand your kind of business I think better one way for you is have universal color attribute (multiply select) and different kind of specific attributes. This will allow customer to see (filter) products by some general color and use additional (specific filters) if you will show it. For example, you can manage filters for each category individually.

Try to group your colors by kind of product without detailed specification:

- `running_shoe_color` - better to have something like `shoe_color`
- `gym_bag_color` - better to have something like `bag_color`
- `tshirt_color` - looks good

Create specific color group only if you have a reason to do.

With specific color attributes you can define some exotic color names (for example shades of green), with universal color you need to compare it to some general colors (example green).